# How to minify jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, optimization, selector, minify

I'm wondering how to minify jQuery selectors:

```
     $("#foo_1").show();

     $("#foo_2").show();

     $("#foo_3").show();

     $("#foo_4").show();

     $("#foo_5").show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're asking for, but you can do this instead:

```
 $("#foo_1, #foo_2, #foo_3, #foo_4, #foo_5").show();
```

Or, you could put the same `class="foo"` on all of the objects and do:

```
 $(".foo").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't change the selectors themselves even if you minify or obfuscate your js as the selectors are css selectors that need to map to the actual DOM